# Previous Button using HTML Form Submit in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am done with my script using form submit. What I am doing is a series of questions per page with a Next Button. Now I would like to add a feature to go back to previous question.

How do I code this in one

```
<FORM name ="Submit1" method ="post" action = <? echo "question.php?num=". $n ; ?>  >
<Input type = "Submit" VALUE = "Next" name ="Submit1" /></FORM>
```

I would like to add the button Previous to the same form without messing the alignment.

I tried making another   and just posted the action to the previous page.

But the button is under the Next or above the questions.

Comment: if you want button Previous you must keep all inputed information as session or cookies.. so you can load them with the Previous button

Comment: I am in session mode already.

Comment: then just set one <A tag with href question.php?num=". $n-1 " and when user click on it, go to prev page and at input load the value for the current question

Comment: I can't, the requirement are Buttons.

Comment: Can you make 2nd form ? for that back button ?

Comment: I could but it will not be aligned with the Next button.

Comment: As I read it this question is not about form submission, but about button alignment. That is a question of your markup and style definitions. You will have to post the full markup and style definitions. Even better: additional put them into a jsfiddle and post the url as addition to the code you add to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FORM name ="Submit1" method ="post" action="/question.php?num=<? echo $n; ?>"  id="formID">
<Input type = "Submit" VALUE = "Next" name ="Submit1" />
<Input type = "Submit" VALUE = "Prev" onclick="document.formID.action = '/question.php?num=<? echo ($n-1); ?>'" name ="Submit2" />
</FORM>
```

Try with that Javascript

```
onclick="document.formID.action = '/question.php?num=<? echo ($n-1); ?>'"
```

This must change the Form action before your form is submitet, to the prev page $n-1 or perhaps it must be $n-2 .. You have to set it correctly